# Can someone explain to me how the loop works here?

Tags: javascript

So I was following a tutorial where if you click a button the background color changes. I've completed the tutorial and I've understood most of the code, but I still can't figure out how the loop to get the hex number works

```js
const hexNumber = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']

const btn = document.getElementById('btn')
const color = document.querySelector('.color')


btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let hexColor = "#";

// I can't understand how the loop down below works

    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        hexColor += hexNumber[getRandomNumber()];
        }
    color.textContent = hexColor
    document.body.style.background = hexColor
})


function getRandomNumber() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * hexNumber.length)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's simpler than you think. Right now you have a variable `hexColor="#"`

As you know, a hex color is made of 6 bits, so you have a for loop from 0 to 5.

In your loop you have `hexColor += hexNumber[getRandomNumber()];` but what is `+=`? The instruction is equals to `hexColor= hexColor + hexNumber[getRandomNumber()];`

So you are appending 6 times a value. But which value? Well, it is defined by the function `getRandomNumber()` which returns a value between 0 and `hexColor` length. It's all here. A for loop which executes 6 times and append one of the array values, so you are going to have the hex color randomly generated.

Comment: Thnx Bro! Really helped me out